# Strange error when trying to save customer data?

Tags: magento2

in the admin when I try to change customer information I get the following error:

```
    "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1910"
```

this is even more strange since it only effects some customers but not all.

Can anyone help with this?
thanks.

Can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: I suggest you **install a debugger and put breakpoints** in the customer save action, from there, go down the trace and see what's going on. From the code you provided, there's no way to guess what's going on, since we don't know anything about your Magento install (version/ edition), customizations, etc.

Comment: @DianaBotean good point; do you have a good debugger in mine? Its a strange problem I'm having and desperate to fix since some clients cannot add to cart! I feel like its a database issue but can't figure out what about it that is causing it.

Comment: I use xdebug. Try it out.